# Stacked barchart same type of variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

I am trying to create a stacked bar plot that will represent this data. The variable n_paper is the total of papers with that method, and the variable paper_ui is how many of that papers use the upwelling index.

```
     n_papers paper_ui               methods
1        6        3                      AR
2        4        2                    ARMA
3        5        4                   ARIMA
4        1        0                  SARIMA
5        6        1     Loess decomposition
6        2        1 Classical decomposition
7        1        0   Exponential smoothing

ggplot(df,aes(x = methods, y = n_papers)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="dodgerblue4", fill="dodgerblue4")+
  scale_x_discrete() + xlab("Time series methods") +
  ylab("Nº of papers") +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=15),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=15),
    axis.text = element_text(size=12),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)
  )
```

The plot is like this but I want the variable paper_ui in that graphic.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You have to reshape your data to long and then plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(-methods) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = methods, y = value,color=name,fill=name)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_x_discrete() + xlab("Time series methods") +
  ylab("Nº of papers") +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=15),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=15),
    axis.text = element_text(size=12),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)
  )
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(n_papers = c(6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L), paper_ui = c(3L, 
2L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), methods = c("AR", "ARMA", "ARIMA", "SARIMA", 
"Loess decomposition", "Classical decomposition", "Exponential smoothing"
)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```